# "we encountered an error while computing the distribution" and "An unexpected error occurred" in Power Query Editor in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have a CSV file that I download from a local machine via an HTTP call in Excel built using the Power Query Editor.  Most of the time it works, but for some reason this URL does not.  It used to work, but then something broke (in the results or in the query, I don't know).  Reverting the changes in both the endpoint and the query, however, has not yielded a fix.  I turned on the `Column Quality` and `Column Profile` options and I get those two errors.  See the example:

[image]

The query code is quite simple:

```
let
    symbol = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="**********"]}[Content][Column1],
    date = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="**********"]}[Content][Column1],  
    query = [
        symbol=symbol,
        date=date
    ],
    Source = Csv.Document(Web.Contents("*********************", [Query=query]),[Delimiter=","])
in
    Source
```

My question is not so much how to fix it, but how do I find out either *what* the error is, or, at minimum, *where* in the data source the error originates.

I don't know if it's pertinent, but if I load the query to a table it loads fine with the columns `Column1`, `Column2`, etc.  However, in the editor, if I try to rename those columns it says that `Column1` can't be found.  Likewise, changing the column types doesn't work either.

Another potentially pertinent issue is that I have a VBA script that refreshes the API call when changes are made to one of two columns.  That code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B2")) Is Nothing Then
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("***************").Refresh
End If
End Sub
```

However, when I make a change I get a popup error saying `Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range` despite the fact that I copied that code from one of a half dozen other working sheets.

Comment: It's completely dissatisfying, but if I recreate this in a new file it works fine.

Comment: I got this same error message when pulling data in from Databricks data lake table. I renamed the column and the error message went away. I deleted the rename step and the error message was still gone. It was some kind of temporary glitch it seems.

Comment: I am getting same error after I change the data type on a column from "any" to "text". If I remove this step, then no error. Not sure what's causing it.

Comment: I had the same problem. However, in my case, the file structure changed and impact the transformation.